# Only last activity gets displayed

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities which do some kind of network access and get a response with 3 corresponding xml layouts (I will call it A,B,C).
A passes data to B through an Intent and B passes data to C through an Intent. When I execute the application, only the third activity/screen shows up on the emulator.

How do I retain the sequence, like A gets displayed first, I hit a button then go to B then hit a button, then go to C. (Do I have to use the activity lifecycle as each activity gets a response after a network access.)

The code (relevant parts) is :

```
A- 
         username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextusername);
         password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);

         submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        //sampletext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(username.getText().length()>0 && password.getText().length()>0)
        {
            URLconnector ss = new URLconnector();
            ss.execute("SOME URL");

        //network access in an async task, get response, 
        }

Intent part of activity A - on post execute method of async task

 if(result != null)
            {
           Intent intentA = new Intent(mContext, B);
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("responsedata",result.substring);

            tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intentA);


B-

 URLconnector ss = new URLconnector();
            ss.execute("SOME URL");

        //network access in an async task, get response, 
        }

Intent part of activity B - on post execute method of async task

 if(result != null)
            {
           Intent intentB = new Intent(mContext, c);



            startActivity(tokenIntent);



c-

 URLconnector ss = new URLconnector();
            ss.execute("SOME URL");

        //network access in an async task, get response, 
        }

Intent part of activity c- on post execute method of async task

 if(result != null)
            {




              text3.setText(result);

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? It will be much easier to help you once you post it.

Comment: @DemVoids Sure, I have posted the relevant parts. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

If the desired effect is to have one trigger the next and you want them to pause in between, then you need to have some sort of block request from the user preventing it from progressing to the next screen.

If you have them just calling one another, then sure, they will fire faster than any visual cues that you have setup to be displayed.  Depending on what you want to do, put up alert messages or provide buttons as you have mentioned to progress forward.  It sounds as though your architectural design would be better off displaying everything you want in one screen instead of using multiple screens in a single activity.  Instead of just progressing through all three.  Perhaps with 2 AsyncTasks doing work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the network responses are huge and would not fit into a single screen (atleast on my emulator).

Comment: If you are just displaying responses that don't fit on a single screen but you are just displaying lots of data, then making the information scrollable should do just fine.

Comment: Aah, so make the view a scroll-view ? Makes sense. Cheers !

Comment: A ScrollView typically surrounds the view you already have in place for displaying the data.  It just can only have one child element.  If you have it designed inside a single layout right now, that should be the only change that you would need to make.

Comment: I meant, I will remove layout C, retain B(just a textview) and make B as a scroll view ? A already has a login screen (user name, password and submit )

Comment: I tried using a scrollview which encloses all 3 text boxes in a single layout,  but only the last textview linked to the last activity is displayed, ? Sorry for the late reply..